# Gmail POP3 with openssl command line: hangs while RETR-ing

Tags: openssl, pop3, gmail

I want to use openssl s_client for accessing Gmail POP3S server.
I am doing the following:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect pop.gmail.com:995
+OK Gpop ready for requests from <removed: ip> d11pf35377217wam.36
USER <removed: user@gmail.com>
+OK send PASS
PASS <removed: password>
+OK Welcome.
LIST
+OK 1 messages (2197 bytes)
1 2197
.
STAT
+OK 1 2197
RETR 1
RENEGOTIATING
```

The problem is I am never able to execute the RETR command. It always hangs while "RENEGOTIATING".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem when testing an SSL connection to GMail's SMTP server.

The `AUTH` and `MAIL FROM` commands worked fine but when I tried the `RCPT TO` the server returned the `RENEGOTIATING` response.

After searching for quite a bit I finally found a site that explained what was going on.

Apparently the uppercase `R` at the start of the command (`RCPT TO` for SMTP and `RETR` for POP3) causes the s_client tool to renegotiate with the server.

The man page for s_client has some info in the "CONNECTED COMMANDS" section.

I managed to get my SMTP test working by using lowercase commands (`rcpt to`). I've just tried a test with GMail's POP3 server and using `retr 1` works well.

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot Kevin.

the retr worked (lower case was correct!)